# SSIS Multiple Data Destinations

Tags: ssis

I'm quite new to Integration Services. Is it possible to have one data source that transfers data to multiple data destinations, or do I have to create as many sources as destinations? I have one CSV file containing data and I must distribute this data to different tables.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In SSIS Data Flow task data flows through "pipes" or "streams". Each pipe can get to one destination only. To split a pipe into several pipes use `Multicast` from the Toolbox, when you are on Data Flow tab. Then link several pipes to their destinations.

Comment: Such a simple solution yet it worked wonders and saved me so much headache. I always overlooked this task!

Answer (score 1):

You can also have multiple Data Flow tasks.  So there can be multiple Data Flow tasks running in parallel (threads) or in sequence.  You can then take the data from one destination table and use it as the source for another Data Flow.